# PRTG PowerShell Remoting Requirements for Custom EXE/Script Advanced Sensor

Tags: powershell, monitoring, remoting, prtg

I've created a script for checking the TLS certificate assigned to an SMTP Relay server which supports SMTPS.  The code is available [here](https://gist.github.com/JohnLBevan/c7974c2839e1486345d63ab6bd76523c) if that's of interest.

The documentation says that powershell remoting is required on the target machine... but it's not clear what's meant by `target`; i.e. is that:

- The PRTG Core Server
- The PRTG Probe Server on which the sensor is configured
- All PRTG Probe Servers
- The Device being monitored

My guess is that it's the device being monitored; but I don't want the script to be run on that device; I want it to be run on the probe but for its result to show under the device (i.e. as I want to show the results when a client connects to the remote service, as part of the purpose of the sensor is to show the port is available externally).

Questions:

- Could you confirm what servers require remoting to be enabled?
- If the script is run on the device under which the probe's configured, is there a way to change this behaviour so I can run it from the probe whilst having the result show against the target device?

Comment: Update: It looks like it's required on [the probe](https://kb.paessler.com/en/topic/84546-exe-script-sensor-powershell-not-running-on-remote-system#reply-295368).  That said, it feels a bit odd as I'd assume the probe is running a PRTG service, so could just run the command locally, rather than requiring the core to push the command to it.

Comment: Note also - lots more useful info here: turns out the execution policy depends on whether you're using PSx64 or PSx86; and PRTG uses the x86 version.  To fix that, run `%SystemRoot%\syswow64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe` in an elevated session, then `if (([int](Get-ExecutionPolicy)) -gt 1) {Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Force}` to make the policy more permissive where required. https://kb.paessler.com/en/topic/71356-guide-for-powershell-based-custom-sensors